# Yum command unexpected behaviour

Tags: ssh, rpm, yum

When trying to run this command:

```
root@491586 [~]# yum install memcached.x86_64 php-pecl-memcache.x86_64
```

I get this:

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
>
> Setting up Install Process
>
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> - base: centos.hyve.com
> - extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
> - updates: mirror.as29550.net
>
> http://pkg.cloudflare.com/dists/el6_6/railgun/binary-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404
>   Not Found" Trying other mirror.
>
> Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for
>   repository:  railgun. Please verify its path and try again

railgun???

Yes I did try to install railgun earlier using "yum install railgun-stable" according to cloudflare [documentation](https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/railgun/installation.html#configuration-and-activation) but then I had to download individual package and successfully installed it.

Now I can't install any other yum package.

I have tried these:

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__*

rpm --rebuilddb -v -v

yum clean all
```

but no luck.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the `railgun` yum repository from `/etc/yum.repos.d`.  All those other commands you've tried have nothing to do with the repositories that yum is looking at.

Comment: Thank you very much... your commend solved it for me. But someone else posted same thing as answer, so going to select that one as correct answer. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured yum with an enabled `railgun` repository only that repository is broken and yum is attempting to prevent you from getting into further harm by only operating when all enabled repositories are available.

There is likely a `railgun.repo` file in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory. You can edit it to changed `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` to disable the repository (newer versions of CentOS/RedHat have a cli tool that can do that for you also but I don't remember what it is called offhand).

But if you don't actually need/want that repository then you should remove it entirely.

If `rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/railgun.repo` returns a package name (and hopefully it will, something like `railgun-release` probably) then you should just remove that package.

If it returns `file /etc/yum.repos.d/railgun.repo is not owned by any package` (or other similar message) then you can just remove the file manually.